# Matching multiple values against an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

My problem is:

I have an array called $ownerArray that another array need to check against and if a key exists in both arrays display the value of the matching key. $ownerArray is populated by a database so i can't just write an ir statement within a if statement.

$ownerArray will look like this:

```
$ownerArray = array(0 =>'Name0',1 =>'Name1',2 =>'Name2',3 =>'Name3');
```

Then I have another array called $Users that has a various number of values depending on what the user selects, so $Users could look like this:

```
$Users = '1,2'
```

or Like this:

```
$Users = '1,3'
```

$Users is never the same.

But I need the $value of $ownerArray to display if any of the values integers of $Users match any $key of $ownerArray

Example:

```
foreach($ownerArray as $key => $value) 
            { 
                if(in_array($key,array($Users)))
                {
                    print $value; 
                } 
            }
```

This method stops at the fist match and displays the correct name. The loop doesn't continue printing if more values match.

What im looking for is if $Users = '1,3' my for loop will print Name1 and Name3 from the $ownerArray.

Thanks for the help!

ps i know i could use if($key==1 || $key ==2) but that will not work for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$merged = array_flip(array_intersect(array_flip($owners), explode(',', $users)));
```

Comment: I do this kind of thing all the time. +1

Comment: `$merged=array_flip(array_intersect(array_flip($owners),explode(',',$user)));` no spacer FTW

Comment: LMOA this is the most straight forward easiest answer to implement. You know you're good

Answer (score 1):

something like this could work

```
<?php

$ownerArray = array(0 =>'Name0',1 =>'Name1',2 =>'Name2',3 =>'Name3');
$users = explode(',','1,2');

if(count($users) > 0){
    foreach($users as $user){
        if($key = array_search($user,$ownerArray)){
            echo $key;
        }
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just invert your logic. You are actually wanting to cycle through your users, and print something if they exist in the owner array, not the other way around. (Apologies if this code is slightly off, but you get this idea.)

```
foreach($Users as $value)
{
  if(in_array($value,array($ownerArray)))
  {
    print $ownerArray[$value]; 
  }
}
```